# Yii2 - warning message before submit

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, alert, before-save

I have a form with two fields "a" and "b" when in action update if the "b" field changes the "beforeSubmit" event a Modal Bootstrap alert is sent to the user without any button `OK` or `CANCEL`, only information during 5 seconds, after this time automatically save if the the "b" field were actually changed, if not change save whitout alert modal windows.

How do I send this condition from the controller to view where I have the javascript?
maybe with ajax? but how?

**Controller.php**

```
public function actionUpdate()
    {
        $model = new Faqs();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            if ($model->oldAttributes["b"] != $model->b){
                sleep(5);
            }

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

**_form.php**

```
$('#form').on('beforeSubmit', function(e) {
    if(old_B_attribute != current_B_attribute){ //example
        $('#modal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: not clear what yo are asking, also you can just call `$model->getDirtyAttributes()` which is actually used when saving or updating a record to determine which fields were actually changed.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam i need show warning modal before submit only when "b" field were actually changed

Comment: ok, and what should happen after the warning modal is displayed is there be some kind of `OK` and `CANCEL` buttons on the modal window which will decide what to do? you should add all the information in the question , about when should the form be submitted and when not? what should happen in case if no value is changed , what shoul happen when any of the `OK` or `CANCEL` button (if there are any) are clicked

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, without any button `OK` or `CANCEL`, only information during 5 seconds, after this time automatically save if the the "b" field were actually changed, if not change save whitout alert modal windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prompt the user if the attribute values were actually changed before submitting the form.

How I would go for this

- Create a separate action in my controller `actionAttributeDirty()` which would validate if the selected attribute was actually changed.
- Then, use a normal `Html::button()` rather than a `Html::submitButton()` for the form.
- Add a hidden field to hold the current records `id` in the form.
- Bind `click` event to the button which will send an ajax call to `actionAttributeDirty()` with the `id` of the current record.
- Then use the success function to display the modal window and use `setTimeout` with `$.yiiActiveForm('submitForm')` to trigger the form submission after 5 seconds.

So in the similar order given above,

**`actionAttributeDirty`**

```
public function actionAttributeDirty()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $id = Yii::$app->request->post('id');
    $model = Faqs::findOne($id);
    $response = ['changed' => false];
    $isValidRequest = Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->isPost;

    if ($isValidRequest && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        //get the name of the fields from the dirty attributes
        $changedAttributes = array_keys($model->getDirtyAttributes());

        //if the attribute name exists in the dirty attributes
        if (!empty($changedAttributes) && in_array("b", $changedAttributes)) {
            $response['changed'] = true;
        }
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Your form should have the following buttons along with other fields,

```
$form = \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form']);
echo \yii\helpers\Html::hiddenInput('id', $model->id);
echo \yii\helper\Html::button('save', ['id' => 'save-now']);
\yii\widgets\ActiveForm::end();
```

**`click` Event for the Button**

Add the following on the top of your view where you have the form.

**Note: change the `url` of the ajax call `'/site/attribute-dirty'` accordingly where you copy the `actionAttributeDirty()` i assume you copy it inside the site controller.**

```
$js = <<< JS
    $('#save-now').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let form = $("#form");

        $.ajax({
            url:'/site/attribute-dirty',
            method:'post',
            data:form.serialize(),
        }).done(function(response){
            if(response.changed){
                $('#modal').modal('show');
                setTimeout(function(){form.yiiActiveForm('submitForm');}
                , 5000);
            }else{
                form.yiiActiveForm('submitForm');
            }

        }).fail(function(response){
            console.log(response.responseText);
        });
    });
JS;

$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

**EDIT**

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> button will not submit the form anyhow as there is no submit button, If you want <kbd>Enter</kbd> button to submit the form you should add the following along with the script too on the top of the view which will trigger the `click` event of the `save-now` button whenever the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button is pressed within any input.

```
$("#form").on('keypress','input',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.keyCode===13){
        $("#save-now").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: fantastic, always available to help, basically you wrote all code for me :) Thanks! I just see that submitting with "Enter" key saves without running javascript because event `$('#save-now').on('click', function(e) {}`..

Comment: i dont think so it should even submit the form on pressing the enter button @Moutinho have you changed the button type to a normal button ?

Comment: see the **EDIT** section @Moutinho

Comment: yes i change the button to `<?= Html::button('save', ['id' => 'save-now']); ?>` but when I press enter it is submitted...

Answer (score 0):

your request can not be done on the client side by beforeSubmit.Because you have to decide on the server side.

On the client side you can use

```
$(document).on("beforeValidate", "form", function(event, messages, deferreds) {
//   #code
// console.log('BEFORE VALIDATE TEST');
}).on("afterValidate", "form", function(event, messages, errorAttributes) {
// console.log('AFTER VALIDATE TEST');
 //#code
});
```

Then decide in the **rules** method.

On the server side, you can also decide on the following events:(For what you want)
 beforeValidate, afterValidate,beforeSave,afterSave,...

Comment: I don´t understand how to check if it is to show modal or not (if field "b" not actually changed) on client side

Answer (score 0):

if you want show confirmation modal i use as below. you can change as your needs show or hide submit after x seconds

```
  $(function() {
    submitting = false;
  });

  $("form").on("beforeSubmit", function (event, messages, errorAttributes) {
    if (typeof(errorAttributes) === "undefined" || errorAttributes.length === 0) {
      $('#modal-confirm').modal('show');
      return submitting;
    }
  });

  var submit = function() {
    submitting = true;
    $("form").yiiActiveForm('submitForm');
  }
```

in modal submit

```
  <button type="button" onclick="submit();">Confirm</button>
```